# Shipping Module Prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.6

Hello i want ask how to set shipping module for prestashop, im already install the module for prestashop shipping. and already set the shipping price and everything. after that how to display this module at front end.
and also there is notification ask me to configure it correctly.

Comment: Please read the module help file and go through the documentation, it should have all the details informations

Comment: its done now cause i forget to include price now solve it :).